# How to insert Calculated fields in pivot table using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus, excel-automation

i am able to create a new pivot table and add row fields, data fields etc. using Epplus but when i try to add some calculated fields in pivot table which takes some formula , Epplus doesn't give any option. Is there any way to add calculated fields using Epplus ?

I have tried the following code :

```
//The pivot table
var pivotTable = pivotSheet.PivotTables.Add(pivotSheet.Cells["A4"], sourceSheet.Cells["A2:V100"], "PivotTable1");                    

//The label row field
pivotTable.RowFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Col1"]);
pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;

//The data fields
var field = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Col2"]);
field.Name = "Count of Col2";
field.Function = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.DataFieldFunctions.Count;                    

field = pivotTable.DataFields.Add(pivotTable.Fields["Col3"]);
field.Name = "Count of Col3";
field.Function = OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable.DataFieldFunctions.Count;
```

Now , i want to add calculated field such as `Name of the field = "Sum of Col4" and Formula = "IFError(col5/col6,0)"` in `PivotTable1`

How to achieve this ?